# Do we need JPA Relationships and Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, criteria, jpql

**Backdrop :**

We are using a legacy custom built Query Generator that basically has all Query related API. It is more or less conceptually equivalent of JPA criteria API. Ever since we moved on from EJB 2 to EJB 3, its dependency on EJB 2 XMLs for metadata is troubling us a lot. One of the problem is that we are forced to maintain/update EJB 2 XML files just for the sake of the Query Generator.

As part of EJB 2 to EJB 3 migration, we created Entity classes for all our tables. But, we did not add relationships between Entities.

Right now we are looking at ways to get rid of it and pretty much we decided to go with JPA.

**Couple of Thoughts :**

Given that Criteria API mandates Entity Relationships i have following thoughts

1. Entity Relationships comes with the baggage of deciding Lazy or Eager. While Eagerly loading causes performance issues most of the times, Lazy loading mandates Open Session In View pattern which has its share of problems
2. Though the Relationships and Criteria API shields developer from database SQLs, that is largely outweighed by the risk of performance impact where a slight programmatic error causes numerous DB sql queries. To avoid that, developer has to work with database which makes database shielding a question
3. As of now, the business logic takes care of which entity to persist before the other. Moving it to Entity layer using CascadeType seems to offer no advantages.
4. JPQL (both NamedQueries and NamedNativeQueries) seems as much powerful as Criteria API
5. Most of the Criteria API materials claim that the Criteria API is the best when it comes to filtering. However, this seems to be hardly true in cases where number of parameters and the table joins are more.

**Questions :**

That said, broadly speaking, Entity Relationships seems to cause more harm than good.

1. What are the real world scenarios to use Entity Relationships ?
2. What scenarios Criteria API outweighs JPQL (Named and NamedNative queries) ?

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Rakesh

Answer (score 2):

For this question, What scenarios Criteria API outweighs JPQL (Named and NamedNative queries)  -

We have restful web services in our project and in our case we need to filter by some properties. If you use query approach as the filtering parameters increase your queries will also increase. In such cases criteria api is better.

In the below example we have 2 query params so both approaches are good. But if you have 4 or 5 filtering query params criteria api is the best option.

```
 public List<AccountEntity> createCriteriaQuery(final List<String> accountIdList,
                final MultiValueMap<String, String> allRequestParams) {

            final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

            final CriteriaQuery<AccountEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(AccountEntity.class);
            final Root<AccountEntity> accountEntity = cq.from(AccountEntity.class);

            final Join<AccountEntity, PlanEntity> account = accountEntity.join(AccountEntity_.planEntity);

            final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
                predicates.add(accountEntity.get(AccountEntity_.id).in(accountIdList));

            if (!allRequestParams.isEmpty()) {
                if (allRequestParams.containsKey(ApplicationConstants.QUERYPARAM_ACCOUNTTYPE)) {
                    String accountType = allRequestParams.get(ApplicationConstants.QUERYPARAM_ACCOUNTTYPE).get(0);
                    if (accountType.equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationConstants.ACCOUNTTYPE_POINT)) {
                        accountType = ApplicationConstants.ACCOUNTTYPE_PTS;
                    }
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(accountEntity.get(AccountEntity_.accounttype), accountType));
                }

                if (allRequestParams.containsKey(ApplicationConstants.QUERYPARAM_PLANNAME)) {
                    final String planName = allRequestParams.get(ApplicationConstants.QUERYPARAM_PLANNAME).get(0);

                    predicates.add(cb.like(account.get(PlanEntity_.name), "%" + planName + "%"));
                }
            }
            cq.select(accountEntity).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
            cq.orderBy(cb.asc(account.get(PlanEntity_.name)));
            final TypedQuery<AccountEntity> qry = entityManager.createQuery(cq);

            return qry.getResultList();
        }
```

Comment: +1 Absolutely. This is pretty much the claim every Criteria API material makes. Let me mention that in the OP. However, I do have reservation when the query gets complex. The bloat only increases with the increase in the table joins and the parameters. Personally i favour Criteria in very simple cases.

Comment: Between criteria api and query approach, we use spring data jpa. So even if we have entities which represent tables, its not always the case that you need to use criteria api. You can still have named queries where needed. I guess thats the same case for you aswell.

Comment: For example like this,  take a look at hibernate docs.       List<CardHolderEntity> cardHolderEntityList = cardHolderRepository.findById(userContextId);

Answer (score 1):

> Entity Relationships comes with the baggage of deciding Lazy or Eager.
>   While Eagerly loading causes performance issues most of the times,
>   Lazy loading mandates Open Session In View pattern which has its share
>   of problems

You may be making JPA more complicated than it needs to be.  Entities are configured by exception, so much of the time sensible defaults are applied to your relationships (eg. lazy for one to many, eager for one to one).  You only need to specify an eager or lazy mapping if your profiling identifies a performance issue related to entity loading.

In particular, a lazy mapping can cause performance problems if the relationship is frequently loaded after all which would cause extra database accesses.  An eager mapping can similarly cause performance problems if the relationship is not used.  These are issues that are always present when accessing highly normalized data and not simply a problem of JPA.

> Though the Relationships and Criteria API shields developer from
>   database SQLs, that is largely outweighed by the risk of performance
>   impact where a slight programmatic error causes numerous DB sql
>   queries. To avoid that, developer has to work with database which
>   makes database shielding a question

In my opinion, the risk to benefit ratio presumed for JPA is overstated.  While you can sometimes achieve better performance by using your own JDBC calls, the performance benefits are generally overstated and must be weighed relative to the other benefits of ORM.  I tend to have the view that "ORM is your friend."

> As expected, the business logic takes care of which entity to persist
>   before the other. Moving it to Entity layer using CascadeType seems to
>   offer no advantages.

Cascading is an option that you can specify in appropriate entities where chaining of operations is germane to the relationship type.  It offers no advantage when there isn't one.

> JPQL (both NamedQueries and NamedNativeQueries) seems as much powerful
>   as Criteria API

They are just different paradigms that can be used to accomplish the same thing.  The Criteria API is a simple DSL that allows you to construct queries upon entity objects by building a family of Java objects using method calls.  JPQL queries are built using strings.

> Most of the Criteria API materials claim that the Criteria API is the
>   best when it comes to filtering. However, this seems to be hardly true
>   in cases where number of parameters and the table joins are more.

JPQL and the Criteria API are different ways of accomplishing the same thing.  They are technologies that are more complementary than conflicting.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. To your 1st point, even when data is highly normalised, JPQL can get data in one query (via constructor expression) where as Criteria does it in multiple queries. For the 2nd point, I never meant to imply JDBC is better than JPA. From query capabilities aspect, i just find Criteria API inferior (reasons as stated in OP) compared to JPQL. While I am of the same opinion that Criteria API and JPQL are never meant to be conflicting, just wondering about serious real world Criteria API use cases that is all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Entity relationships will free you from making individual calls to the Repository, which would happen automatically on Lazy loading. Also you do not want to pass on the entity objects to the Controller anyway as they will then be able to modify your entity outside your business logic. You want to give them the data, not the connection back to the DB. And if you do that, you don't need a open session in your controller.
2. With NamedQueries and Criteria, you truly want to use Criteria when NamedQueries won't work, i.e. when you have a definite predicate, you use NamedQuery. But when your predicate isn't fixed, e.g. you add a price limit in your query when order type is Cash-On-delivery, that has to go thru Criteria.

Having said all these, IMHO the idea of avoiding Criterias and Relationships let you become error prone is a flawed one. You can have the same error on an SQL anyway, that's what Testing is all about.

Cascade is a idea that plays well in some situations, but not necessarily useful in all the cases. If you want be explicit about cascading, it isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. For your point #1, just by keeping session open, controller wont be able to modify anything because it still needs a transaction. If you are talking about transactions in controller then yes. Otherwise, the open session, in general, is more about letting controller access lazy loaded data. I completely agree that Criteria and Relationships doesn't make an application full proof.

Comment: If you have open sessions on your controller, that lets the controller override the model, even if its just fetching data. That's why I said not to pass on the entity object to the controller, so it does only data routing. You have to control what you give to controller to maintain a healthy MVC.